# WooCommerce related products showing the same on each product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a Wordpress site using WooCommerce with quite a lot of products in, the problem I have is that the related product section doesn't seem to be working in that it is supposed to show products related by the category or tags, the problem is that these are showing the same on all products and seems to be showing the products that were recently added.

There has been no customisation to this and it is a clean install of WooCommerce.

I can't seem to find a resolution to this problem around, your input will be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: @Mihai many thanks for your constructive comment - I have given as much information as I possibly could in the hope that somebody might have come across this issue previously.

Comment: Maybe i was too snarky,but without some code I doubt anyone will be able to help.Maybe incompabilities between woocomerce and WP?Check the versions.